# What is the best way to go about running Cat6 over 100 meters?

Tags: networking, cable, wiring, cat6

I have two building about 300 meters apart that I would like to network together using Cat6. I would prefer to wire them together instead of using wireless if possible. Please let me know of any recommendations you may have. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normal solution : Wire them with Cat6 double-shielded at 80 meters length with repeaters at intervals.

Better solution : Run fibre optic in-between and end off with Ethernet Cat6 and hubs on both ends.

[TC3210 Ethernet Fiber Media Converter](http://www.tccomm.com/TC3210.htm) (not very expensive)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have repeaters, it's just not going to work. What about using lasers? We had to do that for a building that is roughly 1km away from the source because the local telecom company would not lease us any fiber optics at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Fiber is preferred anyway for inter-building runs, but copper Ethernet will only work up to 100 m.  What caliban said, except his "better" is the only solution.  If your switches at either end have GBIC ports, you can run the fiber directly without needing media converters.